# openCV Canny edge detection improvement

Tags: opencv, canny-operator

I am trying to use openCV Canny edge detector in my python code. I want to have edge detection along the edge of the object, which is corresponding to the skin.

I did:

```
**im = img[0]
bw = im > thAir
eg1 = cv2.Canny(np.uint8(im),thAir,thBone)
eg2 = cv2.Canny(np.uint8(bw), 0,1)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,4)
ax[0].imshow(im)
ax[1].imshow(bw)
ax[2].imshow(eg1)
ax[3].imshow(eg2)
plt.show()**
```

where thBone is maximum value it can have, and thAir is the minimum value

However, apparently, the detection did not work... Any idea for the improvement?

[imshow results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkH7h.png)

Comment: I would suggest you use cv2.inRange to do color thresholding. Then do your edge detection on the thresholded result.

Comment: I think there was confusion due to the colormap of the figure. Actually, it is a gray scale image...

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of `thAir` and `thBone`? Canny edge detector accuracy highly depends on choice of these thresholds.

Consider also using morphology. You can detect edges for such kind of objects (connected, without holes inside) with morphological gradient, which won't depend on thresholds. 
Documentation for morphology transformations:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex#cv2.morphologyEx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Currently I am only using skimage because opencv does not support dicom image import.. do you know which function in skimage library is compatible to opencv's morphological gradient argument?